# is it Yahoo PlaceFinder API better than Google Geocode API?

Tags: google-api, yahoo-api

besides that yahoo allow more requests/day

but i noticed an interesting bug/case

if I search for "Via Turati, Milan", I would expect to get as result "Via Filippo Turati, 20121 Milan"

you can see google and yahoo results:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=via%20turati%20milan&sensor=false

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=via%20turati%20milano

as you see Yahoo gives me one shot, that is correct, whereas Google gives me several choices wich none of them are good enough...

bad for me i built an app with google but now i'm thinking of moving to Yahoo...

before doing it...someone know if i'm doing something wrong with google api?

Comment: This is quite subjective

Comment: rephrase your question to be something along the lines of "is there anything i can do to get more accurate results from the google api?" and inclde the applicable chunks of your code that you'd like feedback on

Comment: @Robert Levy... The original question was not specific to google api only... the questioner wants the comparison of two APIs... and You wont be glad to know that Yahoo provides more accurate answers and has better error handling .. I am also a google fan but this time Yahoo has won...

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has better error handling. For example if you query for a street number which google cant find. Google's server will slap you an error. Where as yahoo' will gracefully respond by returning the centeroid of that town...